# MS Dynamics - Connect via PHP

Tags: php, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need to connect to the MS Dynamics CRM through PHP

I have looked on the internet but I can not find in what way I can do it.

any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean MS Dynamics?

Comment: Yes, sorry. MS Dynamics

Answer (score 1):

Probably the only clean way to do this will be the Dynmiacs Web API as documented here: [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593051.aspx)

Comment: I use http://phphttpclient.com/ to connect and the response is: `object(Httpful\Response)#8 (13) {
  ["body"]=>
  string(49) "HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied`

Comment: My code to connect i: `$credentials = include("config.php");
    
    $response = \Httpful\Request::put($credentials['serverUrl'])            // Build a PUT request...
    ->sendsJson()                                                           // tell it we're sending (Content-Type) JSON...
    ->authenticateWith($credentials['username'], $credentials['password'])  // authenticate with basic auth...
    ->send();`

Comment: I think is worth a new question here including as much of your code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

My code to connect is:

```
$credentials = include("config.php");

$response = \Httpful\Request::put($credentials['serverUrl'])            // Build a PUT request...
->sendsJson()                                                           // tell it we're sending (Content-Type) JSON...
->authenticateWith($credentials['username'], $credentials['password'])  // authenticate with basic auth...
->send();
```

and the response is:

```
object(Httpful\Response)#8 (13) {
["body"]=>
string(49) "HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied
"
["raw_body"]=>
string(49) "HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied
"
["headers"]=>
    object(Httpful\Response\Headers)#9 (1) {
        ["headers":"Httpful\Response\Headers":private]=>
            array(10) {
                ["cache-control"]=>
                    string(7) "private"
                ["content-type"]=>
                    string(9) "text/html"
                ["server"]=>
                    string(17) "Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
                ["req_id"]=>
                    string(36) "2b132633-9ca3-47c0-9283-0d3fd11541fb"
                ["set-cookie"]=>
                    string(108) "crmf5cookie=!gxLT5kRVUbFsxLk2sMAcTcX9KVcVpQ96ETEp7q4cYuU/v4XeREWZlgu9zG0zcAg/dQ1iVb0zeNKMUP0=;secure; path=/"
                ["www-authenticate"]=>
                    string(223) "Bearer error=invalid_token, error_description=Error during token validation!, authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/60786485-b067-48a0-8533-08bf34ceeef1/oauth2/authorize, resource_id=https://ga-pdes.crm4.dynamics.com/"
                ["x-powered-by"]=>
                     string(7) "ASP.NET"
                ["date"]=>
                     string(29) "Tue, 09 Jan 2018 18:02:24 GMT"
                ["content-length"]=>
                     string(2) "49"
                ["strict-transport-security"]=>
                     string(35) "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AlexaCRM / php-crm-toolkit (https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit) I have managed to connect and obtain data.

I just need to be able to filter data (look for entities filtered by a field).

This is my connection code and data search on an entity

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Client as OrganizationService;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Settings;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Entity\MetadataCollection;

$options = include('config.php');;
$dynamicsClientSettings = new Settings( $options );
$dynamicsClient = new OrganizationService( $dynamicsClientSettings );
$metadata = MetadataCollection::instance($dynamicsClient);

// execute an action
echo("Execute an action - WhoAmI<br />");
$whoAmIResponse = $dynamicsClient->executeAction( 'WhoAmI' );
echo 'Organization ID: ' . $whoAmIResponse->OrganizationId;
echo("<br /><br />");



echo("<b>Lists</b><br />");

$lists = $dynamicsClient->retrieveMultipleEntities("list", $allPages = false, $pagingCookie = null, $limitCount = 1000, $pageNumber = 1, $simpleMode = false);
```

My config.php file:

```
$credentials = [
    // Dynamics CRM URL
    'serverUrl' => 'https://xxxxxxx.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/',

    // System user name
    'username'  => 'xxxxxx@xxxxx.xx',

    // System user password
    'password'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',

    // CRM type (OnlineFederation for CRM Online, Federation for IFD)
    'authMode'  => 'OnlineFederation',
];

return $credentials;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a full sample is shown in Jason Lattimer's [CRMSoapAuthPHP](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMSoapAuthPHP) repository on how to authenticate and work with Dynamics CRM Online and on-premises using PHP.